# Reading Xml file in PySpark via Hadoop Streaming

Tags: pyspark, hadoop-streaming

I'm trying to adapt the code [here](http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/Parsing-a-large-XML-file-using-Spark-td19239.html) from a Scala version to a PySpark version. Here's the code I'm using:

```
    conf = SparkConf().setAppName("Parse Xml File")
    sc = SparkContext(conf = conf)
    sqlContext = HiveContext(sc)

    sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set('stream.recordreader.class', 'org.apache.hadoop.streaming.StreamXmlRecordReader')
    sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set('stream.recordreader.begin', '<page>')
    sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set('stream.recordreader.end', '</page>')

    xml_sdf = sc.newAPIHadoopFile(xml_data_path,
                                       'org.apache.hadoop.streaming.StreamInputFormat',
                                       'org.apache.hadoop.io.Text',
                                       'org.apache.hadoop.io.Text')
    print("Found {0} records.".format(wiki_xml_sdf.count()))

    sc.stop()
```

Error I'm getting is:

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.newAPIHadoopFile.
: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.hadoop.streaming.StreamInputFormat cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.InputFormat
```

Is there a different input format / settings that I can use to make it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest solution is to use [spark-xml](https://github.com/databricks/spark-xml) package. In your case (all documents start with `<page>`) below code will load data into dataframe:

```
sqlContext.read.format('com.databricks.spark.xml')
    .options(rowTag='page').load('samplexml.xml')
```

Comment: I was looking for something more generic. I don't think the underlying file is split with one document per line, which would be required for spark-xml to work.

Comment: spark-xml doesn't need documents in separate lines, you can have big one-line file and it will work. Try it out :-)